# Why is my node_modules folder greyed out after command 'npm install'?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wonder why my node_modules folder is greyed out in my VS Code editor after I run the command `npm install`.

Here the picture of my folder:

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Files/folders that are included in `.gitignore` are greyed out. Normally `node_modules` folder is included within `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 9):

It's because your `node_modules` folder is referenced in your `.gitignore` file.
Visual Studio tells you that this folder is ignored by the version control by graying it out.

Answer (score 6):

As was already pointed out, VSCode automatically ignores everything in `.gitignore`. However, it also explicitely ignores some folders by default. All of this can be configured. Here are the steps you might want to take:

1. Check out [the official documentation on Workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)
2. Open the relevant settings (you can choose between `User` (global) and `Workspace`). I usually do this via `CTRL` (or `Command` on Mac) + `SHIFT` + `P` -> `> settings`, which will show you the relevant choices: [image]. For each you can either choose the UI or the `JSON` variant.
3. Also make sure to check the default settings via `Peferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)`. You will find that, as of now (May 2021), `**/node_modules` is also automatically excluded, independent of other ignore files. Currently the **default settings** look like this:

   ```json
    // Configure glob patterns for excluding files and folders in fulltext searches and quick open. Inherits all glob patterns from the `files.exclude` setting. Read more about glob patterns [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options).
    "search.exclude": {
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/bower_components": true,
        "**/*.code-search": true
    },

    // Controls whether to use global `.gitignore` and `.ignore` files when searching for files.
    "search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles": false,

    // Controls whether to use `.gitignore` and `.ignore` files when searching for files.
    "search.useIgnoreFiles": true,
   ```

### Enabling searching `node_modules`

```json
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": false
  },
  "search.useIgnoreFiles": false
```

- WARNING: This will slow down things *a lot* since `node_modules` takes forever to search through - at least during cold start, that is when things are not cached. (Note that it is difficult to estimate how their caching works since it keeps evolving over time.)
- To mitigate this, you might want to add some additional `search.exclude` settings. Note you will have to **explicitely** list **everything** you don't want, because...

### The big shortcoming of VSCode search

`search.exclude` does not support:

- negative look-ahead/behind
- mutually cascading queries

Things like this **will not** work!

```json
  // does NOT work! :((
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules/@types": false,
    "**/node_modules": true
  }
```

This is a MAJOR problem which has been heavily discussed in the almost famous [issue #869](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/869) for 6 years already! Join in and add to the 100+ comments! :)

**Update**: As of 2021/8/14, the issue has been taken off the backlog queue and put in the [On Deck](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/milestone/27) queue (but that also might not mean much).